# Как реализовать настройки приложения в python?

Tags: python, config

Как я могу реализовать настройки приложения в одном файле? Я хочу, чтобы можно было сохранять и читать настройки

Comment: Советую почитать о YAML файлах - очень удобно хранить и редактировать настройки в YAML файлах...

Comment: Я ввел в популярный поисковик заголовок вашего вопроса и получил довольно внятный ответ, мне кажется, то - что нужно: https://teddyp1cker.wordpress.com/2012/08/02/как-максимально-просто-хранитьзагру/ В следующий раз, прежде, чем задавать здесь вопрос надо делать так, я считаю.

Comment: `JSON/YAML/INI` и прочее.

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень удобный стандартный модуль `configparser`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html